# Uppercase Conversion

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class UppercaseFileConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to be read: Here is the file converted into Uppercase.");
        String fileName = input.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        //validates that the file exists
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The file " + fileName + " does not exist or could not be opened.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //if file exists then reads each line and prints the upper case
        else {
            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

                String line = inputFile.nextLine();

                System.out.println(line.toUpperCase());
            }
        }

        inputFile.close();
        System.out.println("Files read, converted and then closed.");
    }

}
```

When I run my code, my validation that checks whether the file entered exists or not does not run but instead terminates the program. Can I use a try/catch?

Comment: Why do you use `System.exit(0);` in your code,if you do not want to do something ,just remove this line

Comment: Yes there might be exception while checking for file, using try/catch will able to find the exact exception.

Comment: Can you share error logs or it System.exit is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  do three things

1.Remove `System.exit()`

2.Add null Check before using file object

```
if (file!=null&&!file.exists()) {}
```

3.Add `try catch` block to handle possible exception in your case `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: I tried a try/catch block and found that the program executed like I wanted to. Thank you.